# VSCode setup for Python for running configuration

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-poetry

I have a python project with Poetry as the tool for dependency management and packaging.
The project has a lot of test cases and some mocking.
I have an env fine as well where i set some config variables for testing the system.

In Pycharm it is run easily by adding a configuration and selecting the env file and it runs all the test cases and verifies the code.

Is there a way to run this similarly in VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio code you can create different launch configuration by editing the launch.json file inside your .vscode folder. Here you can find everything you need: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging